# Cmake add command line argument to binary

Tags: linux, binary, cmake, command-line-arguments

I create a binary `myBinary` via cmake/CMakeLists.txt.

I would like to "include" default options on my binary.

In other words, I want my binary to be called with `myBinary --option myopt` even when I just run `./myBinary`

How can I do that?

Comment: Not the job of CMake, change your program source code to set default values when arguments are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CMake does not have built-in support for you you want to do.

One solution is to do as @Youka said - change the source code of your program.

Another solution that I have used sometimes is to autogenerate a script that executes an executable:

```
# Create startup script
MACRO(GEN_START_SCRIPT binName)
    # Generate content
    SET(fileContent
        "#!/bin/bash\n"
        "\n"
        "# This startup script is auto generated - do not modify!\n"
        "\n"
        "${binName} -a 23 -b 34 -c 976\n"
        "\n"
    )

    # Write to file
    SET(fileName ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${binName}.sh)
    FILE(WRITE ${fileName} ${fileContent})
ENDMACRO()
```

Then call the macro after defining your executable:

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE(myBinary file1.c file.2)
GEN_START_SCRIPT(myBinary)
```

You can of course add other stuff to the script, like environment variables etc.

Comment: This is a bad implementation of a bad solution. Wrapper scripts like this are pointless in OP's case, since the code can be changed. The wrapper script doesn't forward extra arguments and uses `${binName}` from the `PATH`. Even if a wrapper script were needed, `file(GENERATE)` should be used instead so that `$<TARGET_FILE_NAME:...>` can be used to tolerate changes to the `OUTPUT_NAME` property. In that case you wouldn't need a macro, which should have been a function anyway to not clobber two variables (`fileName` and `fileContent`).

Answer (score 0):

If you're in control of the sources and you want different default behavior... ***change the sources!***

This is in no way a build system issue (CMake or otherwise).